# Accessing nested data in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble understanding when and how to use nested data.

In this example I have a CSV with names ('Name') and locations ('starting point'). By assigning keys to the locations I am able to make a dropdown containing them all, and I would like to use this to filter the names associated with each location.

However I am unable to find the data's values, in this case 'd.Name'

Here inside the update function I have tried to access the 'values' on the data join.

```
  var adventurer = canvas
      .selectAll(".adventurer")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
```

Ive also tried creating an extra data variable but thats not working for me either.

Sorry I can't make a jsfiddle but here is a [plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/ZDNqMB/)

DATA

```
,,Name,First names,s,r,Nat,born,starting point,starting date,arrival date,days,km,Assist,Support,Style,note,arrival date 2
1,1,KAGGE,Erling,,,Nor,1/15/1963,Berkner Island,11/18/1992,1/7/1993,50,appr. 1300,n,n,solo,first solo unassisted,
2,2,ARNESEN,Liv,f,,Nor,6/1/1953,Hercules Inlet,11/4/1994,12/24/1994,50,1130,n,n,solo,first woman unassisted,
3,3,HAUGE,Odd Harald,,,Nor,1956,Berkner Island,11/4/1994,12/27/1994,54,appr. 1300,n,n,,,
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

SCRIPT

```
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv_data) {

  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d['starting point'];})
      .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .entries(csv_data)
  console.log(data);

  //create dropdown select

  var list = d3.select("#menu").append("select")

  list.selectAll("option")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {
      return d.key;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    });

  //chart config

  var w = 375,
      h = 1000;

  var canvas = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate (0,50)');

  //function (bind, add, remove, update)

  function updateLegend(data) {

    var adventurer = canvas
      .selectAll(".adventurer")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })

    var adventurerEnter = adventurer
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr('class', 'adventurer');

    adventurerEnter
      .append("text")
      .attr('class', 'name')
      .attr('x', 0);

    adventurer.select('.name')
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.Name;
      })
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 30;
      });

    // remove old elements
    adventurer.exit().remove();

  };

  // generate initial legend
  updateLegend(data);

});

// handle on click event

  d3.select('#menu')
    .on('change', function() {
    var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    console.log(data)
    updateLegend(data);
  });
```

Comment: I don't see the script in the plunk; it seems to be empty

Comment: `return d.values` isn't going to work because d doesn't have a values field, right? There's no values field in your data.

Comment: The script is in the html. In my console I can see key and values so I thought I could return values as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display both the locations and the names. You have a nest (in the plunk but not in your question) of location/name, but you also need a distinct list of names, or possibly a list of name/location:

```
  var locations = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d['starting point'];})
    .sortKeys(function(a,b){ return a > b && 1 || b > a && -1 || 0})
    .key(function(d) {return d.Name;})
    .entries(csv_data)

  var names = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.Name;})
    .sortKeys(function(a,b){ return a > b && 1 || b > a && -1 || 0})
    .key(function(d) {return d['starting point'];})    
    .entries(csv_data)
```

Then you have to display your names however you want. Then you need an .on('change', function()...) handler (or on click or whatever fits your needs) that actually filters the names wherever those are displayed.

I also fixed your sorting. d3.ascending is for numbers, not strings.

Comment: Im trying to take one column from my data listing locations, and use it (via a dropdown) to filter a list of names. I thought it would be a good idea to group the data by location so that I can use it for my menu. However since I have done that I am unable to access the names to populate the list. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I changed my answer now that I understand the question better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is right either, as wouldn't doing this mean that I would have to create a new nest every time I want to access a new piece of data? Is there a way of importing the csv data that would allow me to easily return d['starting point'], d.days, d.Name etc?

Comment: To the first question: no. You need a distinct list of locations and a distinct list of names. A single nest will only give you one of those. And I don't understand the second question. Any way you import the data allows you to return those fields. What are you trying to do that you can't?

Comment: I'm really appreciating your help by the way! I'm unable to return any fields other than the nested keys. Anything further down the line I can't get access to. To try and simplify, I've asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164974/how-to-use-csv-data-in-d3

Comment: Ok, that question was a lot clearer. You still need to choose locations and then filter on names, which requires distinct lists and a way of associating locations and names. And nest is a way to do that. But you need to understand simpler D3 concepts first.