# How to use CSV data in d3

Tags: d3.js

**What I want to do**

My CSV looks like this

```
,,Name,First names,s,r,Nat,born,starting point,starting date,arrival date,days,km,Assist,Support,Style,note,arrival date 2
1,1,KAGGE,Erling,,,Nor,1/15/1963,Berkner Island,11/18/1992,1/7/1993,50,appr. 1300,n,n,solo,first solo unassisted,
2,2,ARNESEN,Liv,f,,Nor,6/1/1953,Hercules Inlet,11/4/1994,12/24/1994,50,1130,n,n,solo,first woman unassisted,
3,3,HAUGE,Odd Harald,,,Nor,1956,Berkner Island,11/4/1994,12/27/1994,54,appr. 1300,n,n,,,
```

How should I import my CSV so that I will be able to access data such as

```
 .text(function(d) {
      return d['starting point'];
   });
```

**What I've tried**

I have tried nesting the data

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv_data) {
  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.Name;
    })
    .entries(csv_data)
console.log(data);
```

which in my console looks something like this:

```
0: Object
  key: " DICKINSON"
  values: Array[2]
    0: Object
      Assist: "n"
      First names: "Conrad"
      Name: " DICKINSON"
      Nat: "UK"
      starting point: "Hercules Inlet"
1:Object
2:Object
....
```

However I am only able to return d.key

```
 .text(function(d) {
      return d.key;
   });
```

I have asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157825/accessing-nested-data-in-d3/35158095?noredirect=1#comment58035603_35158095) with code examples but I think my question was too confusing. If anyone could help me get to my data I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest it.

```
 d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv_data) {
   select("body")
     .append("div")
    .selectAll('p')
     .data(csv_data)
     .enter()
     .append('p')
     .text(function(d) { d.Name + ', ' + d.location...})
 });
```